# PHP set value to php variable if variable store in database table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my Code

```
table_query
id query
1  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date = "$loc_date"



 <?php
$q1 = 'SELECT query FROM table_query WHERE 1 LIMIT 1';
$result = execute q1;
$query = $result['query'];
    $loc_date = '2017-12-06';
    $loc_query = $query; //This query fetch from table. Not directly write on file
    execute query here
    ?>
```

But I don't get any result after executing query.

Comment: Add all the code . How we can know that you din't have any error in your next code part? The code which is actually necessary is hided by you. Please add that

Comment: String literals should be quoted like date = "$loc_date" in your case

Comment: you can simply change the query in double quotes instead of single quotes and it will work e.g  `$loc_query="SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date = $loc_date";`

Answer (score 2):

You have to write variable in double quotation single quote.

```
$loc_date = '2017-12-06';
$loc_query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date = '".$loc_date."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the single or double quote in $loc_date string

for example

```
$loc_query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date = "'.$loc_date.'"';
```

OR

$loc_query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date = '".$loc_date."'";

Answer (score 0):

Put `""` into the where condition.

```
$loc_query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date = "'.$loc_date.'"';
```

Then execute the query. It should give your result.

Comment: We have one table where all query are stored. and get all that query and execute one by one.

Comment: But In some query we have to pass dynamic value, for ex date, name etc.

Comment: Did You get now?

Comment: No, because the question you posted and the comment you explained are not the same.

Comment: $loc_date declare at the top of php file. and same variable use in query, But this query come form table.

Comment: ok but the query string received from DB will have some specific string to detect and replace the condition there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :)

```
//creates database connection
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
//selects database connection
$database_select=mysql_select_db("your_database_name",$connection);

//put the entered date to loc_date variable
$loc_date='2017-12-06';

//select * date with 2017-12-06 on table_query but would display only 1   since theres a LIMIT
$query1=mysql_query("select * from table_query WHERE date='$loc_date' LIMIT 1");
while($loc_query=mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
echo $loc_query['date']; //prints the date - 2017-12-06 if present
}
```

I think you want to display the date which is '2017-12-06' on your table_query. But since you want to limit the record to be displayed to 1, so only one(1) date which is 2017-12-06 would be displayed on that code. If theres more than 1 record(date:2017-12-06) saved on that table, you can remove the "LIMIT 1" on mysql query so that it will display all.